# Why does len(grid) vs for i in range(len(grid)) make a difference?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

For the code below, which is used for Leetcode #64 Minimum Path Sum, I tried to make the cache grid using " len(grid)" and it does not work for all test cases, but if I do "for i in range(len(grid))" it works perfectly. I'm wondering why this makes a difference if the grid has the same dimensions either way. My code works for the first 2 cases but fails at the third, the code that uses range is accepted in Leetcode. Thank you.

```
class Solution:
    def minPathSum(self, grid: list) -> int:
        # cash = [[-1] * len(grid[0])] * len(grid)
        cash = [[-1] * len(grid[0]) for i in range(len(grid))]
        return self.recursion(grid, 0, 0, cash)

    def recursion(self, grid, y, x, cash):

        # first we check if the space is valid
        if self.check(grid, y, x) is not True:
            return 0

        # then we check if that space has already been cached, if it has, we just return that space
        if cash[y][x] != -1:
            return cash[y][x]

        # this is where the space currently is on the grid
        current = grid[y][x]
        # now check if we are currently at the rightmost or bottommost perimeters of the grid
        if y == len(grid) - 1:  # if at rightmost, have to go down
            cash[y][x] = current + self.recursion(grid, y, x + 1, cash)
        elif x == len(grid[0]) - 1:  # at bottommost, have to go right
            cash[y][x] = current + self.recursion(grid, y + 1, x, cash)
        else:  # if the current value is not at a bottom or right perimeter, keep going
            cash[y][x] = current + min(self.recursion(grid, y, x + 1, cash),  # compare the right block
                                       self.recursion(grid, y + 1, x, cash))  # to the down block
        print(cash)
        return cash[y][x]

    # check if this space exists in the grid using the grid boundaries
    def check(self, grid, y, x):
        return len(grid) > y >= 0 and len(grid[0]) > x >= 0


grid = [[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]
print(Solution().minPathSum(grid=grid))

grid = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
print(Solution().minPathSum(grid=grid))

grid = [[1,2],[1,1]]
print(Solution().minPathSum(grid=grid))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Surely you can build a [mre] that only needs the one function whose code you actually change, instead of including the full solution for the leetcode problem.